# char pointer and printf 2

Tags: c, pointers, printf

please advise me on the following output:

```
int main() 
{

  char ***x = "jjhljlhjlhjl";  

  char ***q = "asddfwerwerw";

  **q = **x;  

  printf("x:%s\n",x);   
  printf("q:%s\n",q);   

}
```

Output: 1 Segmentation fault

Comment: Advice: You don't understand pointers.

Comment: OT: `main()` misses a `return <int value>;` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you should have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  char *x = "jjhljlhjlhjl";

  char *q = "asddfwerwerw";

  q = x;

  printf("x:%s\n",x);
  printf("q:%s\n",q);

  return 0;

}
```

If you want to initialize a character string, use `char *x`
Don't use `***x`. That means pointer to pointer to pointer to a char. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

"Segmentation fault" is not an *output*, it's an indication that your program has crashed.

This should come as no surprise, because string literals are `char*`, not `char***`. Trying to double-derefefence such pointers is undefined behavior, because it re-interprets the content of a string literal as a pointer to `char`. This is what is causing the crash.

You can modify your program as follows to make it legal:

```
int main() {
    char *x = "jjhljlhjlhjl";
    char tmp[] = "asddfwerwerw";
    char *q = tmp;

    *q = *x;
    // This will produce an output that should be easy to explain:
    printf("x:%s\n",x);
    printf("q:%s\n",q);
}
```

Comment: hi, can u tell me how does the string store in "x" if itis define as char***x ? isit not (x -> address1 -> address2 -> address3 "string") ?

Comment: @user1998844 It's `x` that's defined as `char***`, not the string. The string is always a `char*`, so your assignment is illegal. Turn on all warnings to see the compiler complain about it.